# Comparing pandas rows that have identical values in columns, and then group by the unique id

Tags: python, pandas

While there are questions on stackoverflow that somewhat specify the same queries i'm looking to make on a pandas dataframe, none have been able to identify MULTIPLE rows that share the same values.

To explain my issue, I have a dataframe with info on the people/time slot for when they decide to use the gym.
It looks like this,

```
,User,Time,Date
0, User 1 ,12:00PM ,10/5/20             (Identical 3 times)
1, User 2 ,12:00PM ,10/5/20             (Identical 3 times)
2, User 3 ,12:00PM ,10/5/20
3, User 1 ,1:00PM ,10/4/20              (Identical 2 times)
4, User 2 ,1:00PM ,10/4/20              (Identical 2 times)
5, User 5 ,1:00PM ,10/4/20
6, User 6 ,1:00PM ,10/4/20
7, User 7 ,12:00PM ,10/4/20
9, User 1 ,11:00AM ,10/4/20            (Identical 1 time)
10, User 2 ,11:00AM ,10/4/20           (Identical 1 time)
11, User 3 ,10:00AM ,10/4/20
12, User 6 ,10:00AM ,10/4/20
13, User 7 ,10:00AM ,10/4/20
```

My goal is to create a dataframe that would group the "Names" column by the "Time" and "date" for every  row in the frame, which would create a count of Users that share the same signup time/date as another User.
By doing that on the dataset above, it should look somewhat like-

```
 ,User, User, Count of identical gym times
0, User 1 , User 2, 3 
1, User 3 , User 1, 1 
2, User 3 , User 2, 1
3, User 1 , User 5, 1
4, User 2 , User 5, 1
5, User 2 , User 6, 1
6, User 3 , User 6, 1
7, User 3 , User 7, 1
8, User 4 , User 6, 1
9, User 4 , User 7, 1
```

I followed a few guides that tried to count the amount of times that rows are similar,

```
df.groupby('Date').User.nunique()
```

would return,

```
Date
2020-08-20     6
2020-08-21    13
2020-08-22    15
2020-08-23    18
2020-08-24    25
2020-08-25    24
2020-08-26    24
2020-08-27    24
2020-08-28    20
2020-08-29    12
2020-08-30     8
```

This doesnt help. Are there any other guides for this "query"?

Comment: From row 3 to 7 time and date is identical you mean for that specific date and time you want which users where registered?

Comment: I'm more so trying to group up the users that attended the "specific date and time" together, considering that User 1 and User 2 sign up for the same sessions 3 times of the week; i'd like to count all the occurrences. Your answer helped me conceptualize it by placing them into arrays, but now i'm trying to manipulate the arrays to determine the users that sign up together.

Answer (score 0):

Does this output helps?

```
df.groupby(['Time','Date'],as_index=False).agg({'User':lambda x:  [item for item in x]})

      Time     Date                          User
0  10:00AM  10/4/20         [User3, User6, User7]
1  11:00AM  10/4/20                [User1, User2]
2  12:00PM  10/4/20                       [User7]
3  12:00PM  10/5/20         [User1, User2, User3]
4   1:00PM  10/4/20  [User1, User2, User5, User6]
```